# js.erb not getting triggered

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use [this tutorial](https://launchschool.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails) to add new characters to a play model. It's mostly working really well, except that when I click the submit button my form, it does not call my create.js.erb at all. I put an alert('hello') at the top of that file so that I would know if it was called, and it's not.

Other js snippets, like new.js.erb (which renders the form) and destroy.js.erb (which removes a destroyed character from the list of characters) are working correctly.

Here's my code:

View:

```
#bottom of views/characters/index.html.erb
<div>
  <%= link_to "Add Character", new_play_character_path(@play), remote: true %>
</div>    
<div id="character-form" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Form:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for([@play, @character], inline_errors: false, remote: true, layout: :horizontal, label_col: "col-sm-2", control_col: "col-sm-10" ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.select :age, ["Baby","Child","Teen","Young Adult","Adult","Senior"] %>
    <%= f.select :gender, ["Male","Female","Neutral"] %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Controller (relevant bits):

```
class CharactersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_character, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_play
  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
    @characters = Character.where("play_id = #{@play.id}")

  end

  def new
    @character = Character.new
  end

  def create
    @character = @play.characters.build(character_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Character was successfully created." if @character.save
    respond_with(@play)
  end
```

create.js.erb

```
alert('hello');
$('#characters').html("<%= j render(@play.characters) %>");
$('#character-form').slideUp(350);
```

Lastly, my log:

```
Started POST "/plays/5/characters" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-06 14:22:03 -0400
Processing by CharactersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "character"=>{"name"=>"Romeo", "age"=>"Teen", "gender"=>"Male"}, "commit"=>"Create Character", "play_id"=>"5"}
  Play Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `plays`.* FROM `plays` INNER JOIN `authors` ON `authors`.`id` = `plays`.`author_id` WHERE `plays`.`id` = 5  ORDER BY authors.last_name LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `characters` (`name`, `age`, `gender`, `play_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Romeo', 'Teen', 'Male', 5, '2016-07-06 18:22:03', '2016-07-06 18:22:03')
   (87.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/plays/5
Completed 302 Found in 94ms (ActiveRecord: 87.5ms)


Started GET "/plays/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-06 14:22:03 -0400
Processing by PlaysController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
  Play Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `plays`.* FROM `plays` INNER JOIN `authors` ON `authors`.`id` = `plays`.`author_id` WHERE `plays`.`id` = 5  ORDER BY authors.last_name LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `plays`.* FROM `plays` INNER JOIN `authors` ON `authors`.`id` = `plays`.`author_id` WHERE `plays`.`id` = 5  ORDER BY authors.last_name LIMIT 1  [["id", "5"]]
  Author Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `authors`.* FROM `authors` WHERE `authors`.`id` = 4  ORDER BY `authors`.`last_name` ASC LIMIT 1
  Act Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `acts`.* FROM `acts` WHERE `acts`.`play_id` = 5  ORDER BY `acts`.`act_number` ASC
  Character Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `characters`.* FROM `characters` WHERE `characters`.`play_id` = 5  ORDER BY name
  Rendered characters/_character.html.erb (3.3ms)
  Rendered plays/show.html.erb within layouts/application (8.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 662ms (Views: 654.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add :js format in your controller. Try to change

```
respond_to :html, :json
```

to

```
respond_to :html, :json, :js
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you! I feel like I tried that at some other point, but had another problem that was blocking and didn't try it again after I fixed that other bug.